# Link Prediction for directed graph in Python

Tags: python, pandas, graph, prediction

I'm trying to predict the possible future links or missing edges in a directed graph, that is, will there be links between any node pairs in the future?

This is the dataset I'm using right now : https://github.com/JiaCheng-Lai/Link_Prediction

**data_train_edge.csv** is used for training data, there are about 20,000 edges. (This is a directed network, so each node pair represents a directed edge. E.g., (361, 981) represents an edge from node 361 to node 981.)

**predict.csv** is the node pair (node1, node2) to be predicted. The third cloumn *ans* is the prediction result 0 or 1. (0 means there is no hidden edge for this node pair; otherwise the ans is 1.)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

df = pd.read_csv("data_train_edge.csv")

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from(df[['node1', 'node2']].values)
```

I just built a directed graph with the above code, but I'm not quite sure how to do link prediction. You can use any kind of prediction method such as Jaccard Coefficient, Adamic-Adar index, etc.

However, I think networkx does not support link prediction using directed graphs because of Errors. If directed graph really doesn't works, it can be implemented with undirected graphs.

It would be a great help if can provide the code or any tips! Thanks a lot.