# Python - find a simple path in a graph, with gold every y numbered vertex

Tags: python, graph, path

I'm implementing a graph using python.

Each vertex has a list of edges and either has gold (`True`) or doesn't have gold (`False`).

```
    def __init__(self, has_gold: bool):
        self.edges = []
        self.has_gold = has_gold
```

How do I find a simple path, where there is gold every `y` numbered vertex?

So far I've tried:

```
def find_path(graph, start, end, y):
        path = []
        path = path + [start]
        if start == end:
            return path
        if not graph.has_key(start):
            return None
        for node in graph[start]:
            if node not in path:
                newpath = find_path(graph, start, end, y)
                if newpath: return newpath
        return None
```

Not sure if this is right for finding a simple path but hopefully close. Also, how do I check for gold every y numbered vertex?

Comment: There are a few questions here. The `__init__()` method is contained in which class? Tell us more about your `graph` variable. What is your `node` variable and the type of it. The same applies to `start`. I am not very familiar with python 2, but I know that the `dict.has_key()` method was removed in python 3. Instead you would use `start in graph`. Can we work with python 3? Your chances of getting help with python 3 are higher and it is up-to-date. Also, you are adding the empty list `path` to `[start]` and `return newpath` will never execute, because `if newpath:` is never `True`.

Comment: It is also recommended to provide sample data and to show the expected result. And [this](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/tutorial-functions-modify-lists-dictionaries-python/) might be helpful too.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67395244/link-prediction-for-directed-graph-in-python